# Replace values from json

Tags: angularjs, json

I display data from a json. 
I want replace values from an other (for translation).
It's like :

```
    <li ng-repeat="childrens in data.children track by $index">
         <a>{{childrens.type}}</a>
    </li>
```

In 'type' I can have "QUOTE", "BILL" or "DEPOSIT"...
And I want replace this value with the translation.

But I'm beginner in angular, and i work on json for the first time as well, what's the better way to do this ?

I tried to use the fonction replace() in my controller but that doesnt work :

```
   if($scope.children.type =='QUOTE'){
       $scope.children.type = $scope.children.type.replace('Facture');
   }
```

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: for translate better use [angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io)

Comment: I need translation juste for 3 words so maybe it's not enough for use angular translate ? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="childrens in data.children track by $index">
   <a>{{mapObject[childrens.type].text}}</a>
</li>
```

In Controller you can use javascript map

```
$scope.mapObject = {
  "QUOTE":{
    "text":"Facture"
   }
}
```